# Pull array from inside a Ruby string

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string that contains an array;

```
"["item1","item2","item3"]"
```

Is there a slick Ruby way to convert it to this;

```
["item1","item2","item3"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the string. A string can't actually contain an array — it can just contain some text that can be parsed into an array given an appropriate parser.

In this case, your string happens to be a valid JSON representation of an array, so you can just do:

```
JSON.parse("[\"item1\",\"item2\",\"item3\"]")
```

And you'll get that array with those strings.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby has an [`eval` function](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-eval)

```
irb(main):003:0> x = '["item1","item2","item3"]'
=> "[\"item1\",\"item2\",\"item3\"]"
irb(main):004:0> eval(x)
=> ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
irb(main):005:0>
```

It might not be safe to use `eval`, so you might want to consider using [`Binding`](http://rdoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Binding) too.

Comment: This will execute arbitrary code. If anyone but you has any influence over the contents of `x`, they can potentially control your computer. It is *generally* not a great idea.

Comment: @Chuck You are right. Just using `eval` is not a good idea. I was editing my answer to use Bindings on top of `eval`. Thanks

Comment: AFAIK it is quite difficult to come up with a binding that is not potentially exploitable, so I would still not feel good about doing this.

Comment: I'll use Chuck's answer but yours is very interesting. What is eval used for if it is so unsafe?

Comment: @SteveO7: It isn't widely used. It can be used to generate code as long as it's either kept far away from user input or you have really good input validation (for example, Rails used to use eval for most of its metaprogramming, like `belongs_to`, since that kind of model-definition function is obviously not something you're going to pass external input into).

Comment: @SteveO7, If it is your string, then it is safe to use eval.  There is a family of eval functions in ruby that are used to do advanced stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you write

```
str = '"["item1","item2","item3"]"'
  #=> "\"[\"item1\",\"item2\",\"item3\"]\""
```

or

```
str =<<_
"["item1","item2","item3"]"
_
  #=> "\"[\"item1\",\"item2\",\"item3\"]\""
```

or

```
str = %q{"["item1","item2","item3"]"} 
  #=> "\"[\"item1\",\"item2\",\"item3\"]\""
```

then you could write

```
str.scan(/[a-z0-9]+/)
  #=> ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
```